# CSS text color in table cells

Tags: html, css

I have some (actually a lot) of tabular data. In HTML 3.2, I use HTML FONT tags to color the text within table cells (multiple colors in one cell at times) and it works fine.

Under HTML 4.01 strict, I can't (shouldn't) use FONT, because it's no longer supported. Supposed to use CSS, right? I can't use the CSS for the table cell though, because I have to account for multiple colors.

So I have some spans, for instance here is yellow on black...

```
<span style="text-color: #ffff00; background-color: #000000;">text-to-color</span>
```

However, the text appears with the page's text and background colors. Not the colors in the span. This is true in Firefox and Safari.

HTML validator says I'm not making any horrible errors.

I'm confused. Or perhaps bemused.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct syntax is `style="color:#ffff00;"`, not `text-color`.

Comment: Rapid, clear, concise, complete, correct and free of opinion. A poster child for how to best answer a question. Kudos. :) Voted up and selected as "the" answer.

Answer (score 3):

In CSS, the property is color not text-color. :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all your syntax is incorrect, you should use `color` instead of `text-color` and you should not use inline css if you are having table with lots of data...it will be difficult to change the certain type of color if you want to as you have to change each and every style attribute.

You should use internal css or external css and access the colors using id and class, refer http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp

Comment: The syntax error was already addressed by (much) earlier answers and has been corrected. As for your other remarks, the page in question is generated live via python. Changing everything is of absolutely no consequence -- it happens every time the page is produced anyway. However, coming up with every color combination on the other hand for some class is a ridiculous mess to get into for no reason whatsoever. Spans work just fine.